# Angular typescript directive scope empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I'm trying to implement a typescript directive,  but I can't seem to pass my vars to the directive, this is my current directive

```
namespace app {
    'use strict';

    export interface IMyScope {
        // ngModel: Date;
        testing: string;
    }

    class DateTime implements angular.IDirective {
        public restrict: string = 'E';
        public template: string = '<div>Input: {{testing | json}}</div>';
        public scope: any = {
            testing: '='
        };

        // @ngInject
        controller: any = ($scope: IMyScope): void => {
            console.log($scope.testing);
        };

        link: any = (scope: IMyScope , 
                    element: angular.IAugmentedJQuery, 
                    attrs: angular.IAttributes, 
                    ctrl: any): void => {
            console.log(scope.testing);
        }
    }


    angular
        .module('app')
        .directive('dateTime', [() => new DateTime()]);
}
```

but the logs in my link and controller return `undefined`
any clues why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to be working as is. There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7AWJA8CKiENmWW9Mgtnc?p=preview)

Just, if the **`testing`** attribute is not set.. it has `undefined` value

```
date-time without attr testing
<date-time ></date-time>

date-time with attr testing="'xxx'"
<date-time testing="'xxx'"></date-time>
```

I.e. just set the `testing` attribute

Comment: Oh, ok I found what was wrong via your reply I typed `testing="something"` instead of `testing="'something'"` (note: the single quotes) ... :) thanks!!!